# Massless particles in the Lagrangian formalism of special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, vectors, dispersion

In the Lagrangian picture of special relativity we usually define the action $$S = -mc^2 \int d\tau.$$ This is clearly 0 for massless particles, so it says absolutely nothing about their motion. Despite that, from this Lagrangian we obtain momentum and energy (after passing to the Hamiltonian) and eventually conclude $$E^2 = m^2c^4 + {\bf p}^2c^2$$ and *then use this identity even for massless particles*. Why is this fair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It seems overkill to use the [Lagrangian formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) to prove the relativistic dispersion relation. It follows just from

   - (i) that the [4-momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum) $p^{\mu}$ is a [4-vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector) and
   - (ii) that the [invariant/rest mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) times $c$ is equal to the length of the momentum 4-vector$^1$.
2. Nevertheless, if OP is not satisfied by a continuity argument $m\to 0$, and if OP wants to pursuit the Lagrangian formalism, then one should use a manifestly Lorentz-covariant Lagrangian
   $$L~=~-\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2e}-\frac{e (mc)^2}{2} \tag{L}$$
   that works for both massless & massive point particles, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137857/2451) Phys.SE post. One may show that the corresponding Hamiltonian Lagrangian is
   $$L_H~=~p_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu}-\underbrace{\frac{e}{2}((mc)^2-p^2)}_{\text{Hamiltonian}}, \tag{H}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90552/2451) Phys.SE post. The [EL equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for the auxiliary field $e$ yields precisely the sought-for [mass-shell condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell)
   $$p^2~=~(mc)^2,\tag{M}$$
   even in the massless case.

--

$^1$ In this answer the Minkowski signature is assumed to be $(+,-,-,-)$.

Comment: Regarding your first point, I'm not sure how we can really get away from looking at the Lagrangian. I suppose we may simply define the momentum vector in terms of the velocity vector $P = mU$, though without knowing that this actually comes from the Lagrangian we have no a priori reason to expect it to be conserved. I believe introductory books argue this by picturing a collision in two different reference frames, but I just find the Lagrangian approach so much clearer and more systematic.

Comment: Even if we define $P = mU$ why do we expect $P^0$ to correspond to energy? Again this is a consequence of the Lagrangian formalism, but otherwise we would need some kind of argument,

Comment: There's a good explanation of this Lagrangian here https://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2010/08/the-origin-of-the-einbein.html