# Carroll's derivation of the geodesic equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, variational-principle, geodesics

In Carroll's derivation of the geodesic equations (page 69, http://preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/grnotes-three.pdf), he starts with $$\tau=\int\left(-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\lambda}\right)^{1/2}d\lambda$$
and arrives at$$\delta\tau=\int\left(-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\lambda}\right)^{-1/2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\sigma}g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\lambda}\delta x^{\sigma}-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{d\left(\delta x^{\nu}\right)}{d\lambda}\right)d\lambda.$$
 He then changes the curve parametrization from arbitrary $\lambda$
  to proper time $\tau$
  by plugging $$d\lambda=\left(-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\lambda}\right)^{-1/2}d\tau$$
 into the above to obtain

$$\delta\tau=\int\left(-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\sigma}g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}\delta x^{\sigma}-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{d\left(\delta x^{\nu}\right)}{d\tau}\right)d\tau.$$

I cannot see how that substitution works. I've been told it uses the chain rule, but I just can't see it. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Look at your first equation! $\tau = \int X d \lambda\implies d\tau = $?? Then, use $d\lambda=\frac{d\lambda}{d\tau}d\tau$.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94348/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Although my question has been flagged as being asked before and already having an answer, it wasn't answered at the sub-graduate level I could understand. Horus's answer, on the other hand, I could follow, and many thanks to him for persevering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically think of it this way. Take the original equation
$$\tau = \int f(x) \,\mathrm{d}\lambda \tag{1}$$
which in differential form becomes

$$d\tau = f(x) \,\mathrm{d}\lambda \tag{2}$$

after a little rearranging gives

$\frac{d\lambda}{d\tau}$ = $(f(x))^{-1}$--------(3)

with the function $f(x)$ in this case being equal to

$f(x)$ = $(-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda})^{1/2}$--------(4)

as was demonstrated

EDIT:

Using eq (3)

$\frac{d\lambda}{d\tau}$ = $(f(x))^{-1}$ = $(-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda})^{-1/2}$

Substitute into

$\delta\tau = \int$ $(-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda})^{-1/2}$ $(-\frac{1}{2}$$g_{\mu\nu,\sigma}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}{\delta}x^{\sigma}-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{d({\delta}x^\nu)}{d\lambda})$ $d\lambda$

gives

$\delta\tau = \int$ $\frac{d\lambda}{d\tau}$ $(-\frac{1}{2}$$g_{\mu\nu,\sigma}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}{\delta}x^{\sigma}-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{d({\delta}x^\nu)}{d\lambda})$ $d\lambda$

$\delta\tau = \int$ $\frac{d\lambda}{d\tau}$ $(-\frac{1}{2}$$g_{\mu\nu,\sigma}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}{\delta}x^{\sigma}-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{d({\delta}x^\nu)}{d\tau})$ $\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda}$$\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda}$ $d\lambda$

Use chain rule to get

$\delta\tau = \int$  $(-\frac{1}{2}$$g_{\mu\nu,\sigma}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}{\delta}x^{\sigma}-g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{d({\delta}x^\nu)}{d\tau})$ $d\tau$

Here I use , to represent the partial derivative with respect to $x^\sigma$.

Comment: Sorry, I realise I'm missing the blindingly obvious here (and being close voted to oblivion), but I can't still can't see how all those denominator $d\lambda$s become $d\tau$s. Do I substitute $d\lambda=\frac{d\lambda}{d\tau}d\tau$ for every single $d\lambda$?

Comment: No just the one at the end of the integral. It should work after using the chain rule.

Comment: @Horus - in your second-last step, where has the second $\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda}$ come from in the integrand? I can see that you've multiplied through by $\frac{d\lambda}{d\tau}\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda}$ to replace $d\lambda$ with $d\tau$ in each term. This leaves you with one $\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda}$, but I'm puzzled as to where the second one has come from? I looked at the other question on the same topic (linked), but found this step similarly opaque in that answer...

Comment: (The equivalent step in the top-rated answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94348/geodesics-equations-via-variational-principle) is the step from eq. (1) to eq (2), but there seems to be a totally arbitrary change from $\frac{dx^\beta}{d\lambda}$ in the second term of eq. (1) to a corresponding $\frac{dx^\beta}{d\tau}$ in the second term of eq. (2))

Comment: Well, I think I get it now. Very well explained. Thanks.

Comment: @tok3rat0r - hasn't Horus multiplied through *twice* by $\frac{d\lambda}{d\tau}\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda}$? That gives the $\frac{d\lambda}{d\tau}\frac{d\lambda}{d\tau}d\lambda$ term at the end, which cancels to give $d\tau$.

Comment: @Peter4075 - just realised this a few minutes ago; I'd completely missed the fact that the terms in brackets are both double derivatives! All finally becomes clear...

Comment: I've fixed the first two equations here. Note the use of blocktset equations (use `$$`, not `$`), the use of `\tag{}` to get numbering, and the use `\mathrm{}` to force the typesetting of differentials in the conventional upright text, and finally the use of `\,` if you want to forcibly insert a thin space.

Comment: And while you're at it, we have revision histories, so you don't need [to add "edit"](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5886/) to your post. You might want to consider reformatting the post slightly to eliminate the need for "edit".