# Variational formulation of distance and its connection to the principle of least action

Tags: metric-tensor, variational-principle, geodesics, distance

My question comes from reading about distances on Wikipedia, and seeing the phrasing *[Variational formulation of distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Variational_formulation_of_distance)*. I am not very comfortable with vector notation, so I've rephrased the math slightly (hope it is correct).

Basically, the Euclidean distance between two points on $\mathbb{R}$ $A$ and $B$ can be written in *variational* form where the distance is the minimum value of an integral:

$$D=\int_0^T\sqrt{\left( \frac{\partial|h^*-h_t|}{\partial t}\right) ^2}dt$$

where $|h^*-h_t|$ is the simple (Euclidian) distance between two points at time $t$. This distance is the minimal value of the integral when $h^*=h_t$.

---

**Questions**:

1. Is my reformulation done correctly?
2. Why, intuitively, is the above formulation a partial derivative with respect to time?
3. How would this look if generalised to $\mathbb{R}^n$, still keeping my naïve and space consuming notation?
4. Is there a simple way to prove that the integral is at its minimum when $h^*=h_t$?
5. How does this, intuitively, relate to the [principle of least action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action)?

---

This is a [crosspost](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2038957/11127) from Math.SE, but I think that the question is closer to physics.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94348/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, when adding $h^*(t)$, you are modifying the integrand which is not anymore equal to speed $\times$ time increment, which it should be. Besides, you added an unnecessary $t$ subscript to $h$.
2. It is wrongly written as partial derivative, there is only one argument in $h$ so you can write as well $\frac{d}{dt}$.
3. The wikipedia article is already written in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (see arrow on $r$), you wrongly interpreted it as being in $\mathbb{R}$.
4. the integral (the correct one from the wikipedia article) is at its minimum when $h=h^*$ by the very definition of $h^*$.
5. It relate to the principle of least action because the varying integral is minimized.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Is there a way to formulate the *correct* integral not using tensor notation? E.g. referring to two points in dimension *i*. I am interested in both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I see no simpler formulation than the one in the wikipedia article you linked to. The points $\vec{r}(t)$  describe a trajectory in $\mathbb{R}^n$, what's the problem with this notation? You can remove the arrow if you want, but the object remains the same, a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.